# mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to do a username search [which I seemingly finished and working as well] but when you've searched for the username, the information about the account will show up. For example, I've searched for *virtualAnon*, his name and information such as *first_name* will show up after his username.

I've tried to fix it by replacing `$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username like ? LIMIT 1";` to `$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username like ? LIMIT 1";` but after I've tried that, the error

> mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match
> number of fields in prepared statement in PHP

shows up.

**This is the PHP file to fetch usernames and database:**

```
<?php
    if($_GET['keyword'] && !empty($_GET['keyword']))
    {
        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','loginsecure'); //Connection to my database
        $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
        $search = $_GET['keyword'];
        $keyword="%$keyword%";
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username like ? LIMIT 1";
        # When I tried to SELECT *, It gives me the error of: Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in ...\fetch.php on line 22
        $statement = $conn->prepare($query);
        $statement->bind_param('s',$keyword);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->store_result();
        if($statement->num_rows() == 0) // so if we have 0 records acc. to keyword display no records found
        {
            echo '<div id="item">Sorry, but there is no user "'.$search.'" found in our database :(</div>';
            $statement->close();
            $conn->close();

        }
        else {
            $statement->bind_result($name); # There is a error i'm encountering when I try to Select * from the line 8.
            while ($statement->fetch()) //outputs the records
            {
                echo "<div id='item'><a href=\"../user/username.php?username=$name\">$name</a></div>";
                # It supposed to show more information about the user, by using $name['first_name'] or $name['last_name']
            };
            $statement->close();
            $conn->close();
        };
    };
?>
```

Comment: `if($_GET['keyword'] && !empty($_GET['keyword']))`  is not advisable.  Just remove the first check and rely fully on the second.  This way you would prevent generating notices.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you're getting is that [`mysqli_stmt::bind_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) will try to bind each column in the result set to a variable. Which means that you need the same amount of variables as you've got columns. If you've got two columns being returned, you need to bind them to two variables.

In `$statement->bind_result($name);`, you're saying *"There's only going to be one column, so bind it to `$name`"* whereas your query (`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username like ? LIMIT 1`) is fetching all the columns for that table.

So the solution is to only select the singular column you want in this instance. Replace

```
SELECT name
```

with

```
SELECT *
```

Comment: Sorry for that, so, I've made a new variable, which is the `$namequery = "SELECT first_name FROM users";`, and I changed `$statement = $conn->prepare($query);` to `$statement = $conn->prepare($query, $namequery);`. Now it throws the error of **Warning: mysqli::prepare() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2** and **Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on null**

Comment: Well, you can only prepare one query at a time. They each have their own statement, so you can't prepare two queries and end up with one statement. That being said, you don't need a *new* query, just change `$query` to `$query = "SELECT first_name FROM users WHERE username like ? LIMIT 1";`

Comment: I've used your code, and it works. But only thing is I just want to display the username **and** the username name.

Comment: So, if you read the link to the PHP Manual on bind result, in your SELECT statement you define the two columns that you want (`SELECT first_name, username ...`) and then use `bind_result` on two variables (`$statement->bind_result($name, $otherColumn)`. Check out the manual link in my answer, it'll explain in more detail